# Set CSS Grid number of columns dynamically on the basis of list items

Tags: html, css, css-grid, freemarker

I have a dynamic list to display as a grid under a dropdown.
I want to split the list in two columns when the number of items exceed 15, and display only one column if the number of items is less that 15.
I am using freemarker on the server end to get the list.

```
<style>
.list {
 display: grid;
grid-template-columns: repeat(2, auto);
grid-auto-rows: 40px;
}
</style>
<#list list as item>
<ul class='list'>
<li>
  <a>${item.title}</a>
</li>
```

I am setting the grid-auto-rows to 40 px so to limit it's size.
The list appears to split in two columns even if there are very less number if items. Is there any way I can make it more dynamic?

Comment: No, you can either set the number of columns or the width of each column...you can't make it dynamic as CSS cannot know how many columns/items there are.

Comment: You will need JS to determine how many items there are and apply a suitable media query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use grid-template-rows: repeat to do that like this:

```css
.list {
  list-style: none;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(15, 45px);
  gap: 10px;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
}

.list-item {
  background: black;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 10px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<ul class='list'>
  <li class="list-item">
    <a>item</a>
  </li>
  <li class="list-item">
    <a>item</a>
  </li>
  <li class="list-item">
    <a>item</a>
  </li>
  <li class="list-item">
    <a>item</a>
  </li>
  <li class="list-item">
    <a>item</a>
  </li>
  <li class="list-item">
    <a>item</a>
  </li>
  <li class="list-item">
    <a>item</a>
  </li>
  <li class="list-item">
    <a>item</a>
  </li>
  <li class="list-item">
    <a>item</a>
  </li>
  <li class="list-item">
    <a>item</a>
  </li>
  <li class="list-item">
    <a>item</a>
  </li>
  <li class="list-item">
    <a>item</a>
  </li>
  <li class="list-item">
    <a>item</a>
  </li>
  <li class="list-item">
    <a>item</a>
  </li>
  <li class="list-item">
    <a>item</a>
  </li>
  <li class="list-item">
    <a>item</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: note: you can use CSS var() to easily reuse and reset numbers of item per col to lay. https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/mdWPPrE ;)